# byte order of P6 ppm image in C

Tags: image-processing, c

this is the main function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "improc.h"

int main()
{
    uint32_t *sample = malloc(WIDTH*HEIGHT*sizeof(uint32_t));
    char *filename = "input.ppm";
    sample = load(filename);
    save(sample, "output.ppm");
    return 0;
}
```

improc.c

```
#include "improc.h"

void fill(uint32_t *image,  int color)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT*WIDTH; i++)
        image[i] = 16711935;
}
int save(uint32_t *image, char *filename)
{
    FILE *output = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (output == NULL)
        return -1;
    fprintf(output, "P6\n%d %d\n255\n", WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    for (int row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < WIDTH; col++) {
            uint8_t pixel[3] = 
            {
                image[row*WIDTH + col] >> (8*1),
                image[row*WIDTH + col] >> (8*0),
                image[row*WIDTH + col] >> (8*2)
            };
            fwrite(pixel, sizeof(pixel), 1, output);
        }
    }
    fclose(output);
    return 0;
}
uint32_t *load(char *filename)
{
    FILE *input = fopen(filename, "rb");
    uint32_t *img = malloc(WIDTH*HEIGHT*sizeof(uint32_t));
    char buffer[16];
    fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, input);    
    for (int row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < WIDTH; col++) {
            uint8_t pixel[3];
            fread(pixel, sizeof(pixel), 1, input);
            img[row*WIDTH + col] = (pixel[0] << 16) | (pixel[1] << 8) | (pixel[2] << 0);
        }
    }
    return img;
}
```

my question is what is up with the ordering of pixels in the save function, if I make it anything else, the colors appear swapped.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in how you read the PPM file:

```c
    char buffer[16];
    fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, input);
```

This means you always read 16 bytes, no matter how many bytes are used in the header. The PPM header writes the image sizes in plain text, so a larger image will use more bytes for the header than a smaller image.

Because you're not reading the right number of bytes for the header, the alignment is off when reading the 3 bytes for each pixel. For example, maybe the GB values from one pixel in the file end up interpreted as the RG values, and the R value from the next pixel as the B value.

The P6 PPM header is composed of three lines terminated by newlines. You can read the header with:

```c
   size_t n = 0;
   char *buffer = NULL;
   getline(&buffer, &n, input);
   getline(&buffer, &n, input);
   getline(&buffer, &n, input);
   free(buffer);
```

Obviously you should interpret the values read and take the `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` values from there rather than using hard-coded values, but you already knew this presumably.

Another issue in the code is that `main()` allocates `sample`, but that buffer is never used. `load()` then allocates another buffer. Neither of these buffers are freed. `main()` should end with `free(sample)`.